# why use a perceptron when it seems multiple IF staments do the same thing

Tags: machine-learning

If we are to stick with an X and Y axis, the X axis being Time and the Y axis being test scores. Where more time equates to High test scores. You can use a binary classifcation algorithm to predict success. Wouldn't 2 if statements do the same thing

```
If (time > someValue)
   User will probably pass
```

**Another Scenario
Is I have papayas, and they have two labels, squishness and color.**

```
If the squishness is greater then 7 //on a scale of 1-10
   AND the color is green 
     Then it is a good papaya

Else 
   It isn't ripe.
```

I dont understand the value of a perceptron in these scenarios.

Comment: @neil slater Can you show me an example, or point to some tutorial website that demos that? I have the Python Machine Learning book, and have been reading around the web and have not seen an example of such. thank you for the quick response also!

Comment: A better comparison would be with a decision tree, not a perceptron.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Machine learning (perceptrons or not) is all about **automatically** finding generic but correct rules, be it in the form of If-Else-Rules, encoded formulas, closest occurrences, or others.

The ML algorithm is just a way to (automatically) find this knowledge, whatever the representation may be. In another words, you use it to find the `someValue` of your example, based on your data. You don't *need* ML if you can represent such knowledge yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perceptrons *can indeed* be implemented using this kind of boolean logic. Perceptron training is about finding suitable values to go into the if/else expressions, using example data. In your first example `someValue` has to be discovered, from known practice time and test results. In your second example `squishiness > 7 and colour >= green` has to be discovered by measuring some papayas.

In the more general case, the perceptron finds a hyperplane (line in 2D, plane in 3D) that discriminates between two target classes based on the input feature vector $\mathbf{x}$. That hyperplane could be in any direction and is expressed mathematically in terms of the input features. It still can be expressed as an if/else statement though:

If $\mathbf{\theta}^T \mathbf{x} + b > 0$:
$\qquad$class A
Else:
$\qquad$class B

The perceptron training finds parameter vector $\mathbf{\theta}$ and scalar value of bias $b$.

Answer (score 0):

### When should I use machine learning?

Machine learning should only be used if there is no reasonable other way:

- **Automatic Speech Recognition (ASR)**: We can't manually design how we recognize language by rules. It is too complex, often fuzzy and a lot depends on context. The same is true for various **Computer Vision (CV)** tasks.
- **Natural Language Processing (NLP)**: Let it be automatic summarization, translation or sentiment analysis. Additionally to the problems in ASR and CV it has a lot of special cases. While we might be able to recognize those if phrased correctly, it is in many cases absolutely hopeless to write them all down and keep them up to date.

### What is the perceptron good for?

It's good for learning how multilayer perceptrons (MLPs) work. I'm not sure if there is any real use case where you would want to apply a perceptron.

Decision stumps (if-statements) are extremely simple, just like perceptrons. If such a simple model is enough, you could probably also just set it by hand.

(Please let me know in the comments if you know an example where a single perceptron / decision stump with the associated learning method provides value compared to an ad-hoc decision method)